# MVC View Management

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I am in the process of making a few reusable MVC features and want to include the views within the DLL to make them accessible from multiple MVC implementations. I am working with MVC 5 in case it impacts how this should be done.

I've done some research on this, and have found a few ways this is possible, but many of the articles seem outdated as they are for earlier versions of MVC. Examples include:

- 2012: [ASP.Net MVC Plugins](http://maxtoroq.github.io/2012/02/aspnet-mvc-plugins.html)
- 2011: [Embedding Razor views in class library as resources](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4616511/embedding-razor-views-in-class-library-as-resources)
- 2009: [Embedding View files as resource inside Binary](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/669088/embedding-view-files-as-resource-inside-binary)

The end goal is to have a project structure similar to this:

```
- Shared MVC Module
    - Includes Views for Module features

- First MVC Implmentation
   - Consumes Shared MVC Module
- Second MVC Implmentation
   - Consumes Shared MVC Module
```

What are the primary recommended methods for allowing this to be done in a simple fashion? We are currently copying the views around but want a better system.

Comment: What exactly is the difference between xcoping DLLs vs .cshtml files?

Comment: We want to reference the Projects, and thereby the .cshtml files, within the solution for debugging rather than doing file copies.

Comment: Although not directly for 'views' and cshtml, the simplest way to do this is with HtmlHelpers which _can_ be easily ( / are designed to be ) built into DLLs and deployed with NuGet etc.  But you write the html in the code-behind.  This is how all the `EditorFor` etc in MVC are written.  So depends on how complicated the views are.

Comment: You can also provide files (including cshtml) in a nuget package - so that your consuming project imports the files as needed via nuget and can be upgraded by upgrading the package etc (disclaimer: I've never actually done this with view files...but should be possible in theory).

Comment: As everything is in the same repository, I feel that NuGet is the wrong path for this. We have 3 application projects that need to share certain modules such as discussions or client management. Debugging and updating is much easier if they are using direct project references than going through the overhead of creating NuGet packages.

Answer (score 1):

I faced the same problem, and the best solution I found was [RazorGenerator](https://github.com/RazorGenerator/RazorGenerator).

It consists of 2 parts:

1. a Visual Studio extension that will precompile your views. This way, they will be included as compiled classes in your DLL.
2. a runtime DLL that provides a view engine implementation that can use those precompiled views.

I've been using that in a few projects, and it works quite well. In particular, I like the fact that if I add the RazorGenerator view engine **after** the regular Razor engine, I can override the precompiled views in the project that uses them, this gives quite a lot of flexibility.

Comment: I will look into that option. It sounds like it may be just what we are looking for.